# reading data file into string using string tokenizer

Tags: structure, binary-tree, stringtokenizer, readfile

hi I have this code for reading text file into string

```
void addStu    (BST_TREE* list)
{
// Local Declarations
   COMPANY* stuPtr;
   FILE* fp;
   int i = 0;
   char fileName[25];
   char buffer [100];
   char* tempString;
// Statements

   stuPtr = (COMPANY*)malloc (sizeof (COMPANY));
   stuPtr->name = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   stuPtr->market = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   stuPtr->initial = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   tempString = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));

   printf("Enter the file name: ");
           gets(fileName);
           fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
           if(fp == NULL)
           {
              printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
              exit(101);
           }
   while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
        {
            if (!stuPtr)
                printf("MEmory overflow!\n"), exit(101);
            tempString = buffer;
            stuPtr->name = strtok(tempString, ";");
            sscanf(buffer, "%15s   %15s    %f ", stuPtr->market, stuPtr->initial, &(stuPtr->stock));
            BST_Insert(list, stuPtr);
            i++;
        } // end while

} //addStu
```

this code does not work properly since buffer keep on changing when i didn't even modify it

this is my input

```
Microsoft Corporation;   NASDAQ MSFT    259.94B  
Yahoo! Inc.;             NASDAQ YHOO    37.67B  
Baidu.com, Inc. (ADR);   NASDAQ BIDU    8.64B  
CNET Networks, Inc.;     NASDAQ CNET    1.13B  
QuickLogic Corporation;  NASDAQ QUIK    88.62M  
Answers Corporation;     NASDAQ ANSW    53.49M  
Apple Inc.;              NASDAQ AAPL    114.17B
```

for example when I tried to read the first line, i was able to get stuPtr->name to contain `Microsoft Coporation` using string token, after this point the tempString would be modify to contain `Microsoft Coporation` as well, for some reason the buffer that was not suppose to change, changed as well leading to `stuPtr->market`, `stuPtr->initial`, and `stuPtr->stock` have the wrong input value.

why did buffer change without being modify? how can I fix this code to make it work ?

thank in advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

**`strtok()` has unexpected side-effect for OP.**

After `stuPtr->name = strtok(tempString, ";");`, the `buffer` location formerly occupied by the ';' is replaced by a '\0'.  So when `sscanf(buffer, "%15s ...` is called, unexpected results occur.  Recommendation: consider alternatives other than mixing `strtok()` and 'sscanf()`.

One *could* continue on using `sccanf()` with

```
sscanf(&buffer[strlen(stuPtr->name)+1], "%15s ...
```

But recommend a `sscanf()` only solution **or** a `strtok()`, `strtof()`.